# Is possible to construct a fixed set of typeclases as powerful as unconstrainde typeclasses?

Tags: type-theory, haskell

We can construct a fixed set of combinators with a computational power equivalent to lambda calculus.

Can we do the same with typeclasses (ad-hoc polymorphism)?

For example, construct a finite set of typeclasses from which we can build general ad-hoc polymorphic functions?

Comment: can you please add an example as to what exactly you are looking for. More specifically, what are you going to use the general ad-hoc polymorphic functions for?